# ROOM how to swap two entity for Drag & Drop in list

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am learning how to use ROOM as part of Android Architecture Components. For a regular recyclerviews, I am able to implement `onSwipe` to delete a post on the list easily and my `ViewModel` will directly calls my repository to call ROOM to delete the given post.

However, I ran into some issues when I tried to also implement the `onMove` callbacks. the callback listed as below:

```
public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView,
                      @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                      @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target)
```

from here i can get the before and after positions, my naive thinking is that I should be able to **swap** these two post in my Repository and my LiveData will update the list automatically.

But I don't know how to do the operation (**swap**) on `DAO` and `ROOM` parts. Can you please share your idea or correct me if I am heading to the wrong direction?

Answer (score 1):

In your repository you  will find something like :

`var allRecords : LiveData<List<Record>> = fragmentDao.getAllRecordsOrderedByIDDesc()`

This ensures that the feed into Recycler display (i.e. LiveData) will be current with any inserts, updates etc, to the database.

In the DAO you'll see something like:

```
@Query ("SELECT * from record_table ORDER BY id DESC" )
fun getAllRecordssOrderedByIDDesc(): LiveData<List<Record>>
```

Since you cannot modify id after drag and drop, you'll need a new database column to record position. Let's call it 'position'. Your LiveData would now be:

```
var allRecords : LiveData<List<Record>> = fragmentDao.getAllRecordsOrderedByPositionDesc()
```

based on:

```
@Query ("SELECT * from record_table ORDER BY position DESC" )
 fun getAllRecordssOrderedByPositionDesc(): LiveData<List<Record>>
```

Once a new position is recorded in the database, it is persistent i.e. you can stop the app, restart it, and the record will still appear in the new position (LiveData is using positions read from the database, as described above).

Another approach is to use preferences to record drag and drop changes. After the database is loaded these are then applied. There are pro and cons. Updating a position in a database might be done with a database update, called after recyclerView.adapter.notifyItemMoved(from, to) (in override fun onMove), in override fun clearView.

You'll need code to determine new positions. It is more complex than 'item at position 3 goes to position 5).For example, dragging item at adapter position 3 to position 10 implies the following changes:

```
3 -> null
4 -> 3
5 -> 4
...

9 -> 8
10 -> 9
and finally 3 -> 10
```

The java.util, Collections.swap can be used:

```
from = viewHolder.adapterPosition
to = target.adapterPosition
Collections.swap(mutableList, from, to)
```

in override fun onMove(...) You can then use the mutableList to drive the database position update.

Answer (score 0):

[For drag and swipe in recyclerview follow this url](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf)

However ,If you want to persist the new order of list .

- maintain the position in table like 1,2,3....
- fetch the list using Room query - sort the items using position
- user drag and drop ,update the new positions in database

  - to get positions => viewholder.getAdapterPosition() ,target.getAdapterPosition()
- Livedata will be fired when there is change in database ,you will get new list from database.

Comment: I read about the post before. but i was not really sure about how to implement the part "update the new position in the database". Can you provide some sample code snippet? I think only if we can update the database, then livedata will kickin to update UI automatically, right?

Comment: @IHC_Applroid .. yes ,you need to just update positions in database ,livedata will give callback to update ui with new list . Set updated list to adapter and call notifydatasetchanged() .

Comment: this goes back to my OP, i am not sure how to swap the position.

Answer (score 0):

About the sorting problem.
When drag and dropping the item, each of every data in entity need to be in the right position, I think I have the perfect solution.

Btw, my answer is based on @NY-Newboid, which by adding a new column section just to locate the position of each of the data in the entity.

And FYI, I am using Kotlin.

[When item is dragged....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrVzD.png)

When the item is dragged, like in this picture, the fun onMove will be called twice. On each of the call, only 2 of the item will be affected.
So we can just use `@update fun update(item1 : Entity,item2 : Entity)` on each of the onMove call, to switch between the position of 2 of the item. And the data in the entity will rearrange one by one like climbing up a stair. Eventually will stop doing this when the user dropped the item.

This is my code on Note database project,

In Note Data Class

```
@Entity(tableName = "note_table")data class Note(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var id: Int,
val title: String,
val description: String,
val position: Int
```

)

In DAO

```
@Update
suspend fun update(note1: Note, note2: Note)
```

In ActivityMain

```
override fun onMove(
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        ): Boolean {

            val fromPosition = viewHolder.adapterPosition //started position
            val toPosition = target.adapterPosition //ended position

            val oriNote1 = noteAdapter.getNote(fromPosition) //note that are dragged
            val oriNote2 = noteAdapter.getNote(toPosition) //note that are affected
            val newNote1 = Note(oriNote1.id,oriNote1.title,oriNote1.description,toPosition)
            val newNote2 = Note(oriNote2.id,oriNote2.title,oriNote2.description,fromPosition)
            noteAdapter.isItemMoved() //setting up boiler code to disable notifyDataSetChanged()
            noteViewModel.update(newNote1,newNote2)
            noteAdapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition,toPosition)
            return true
        }
```

In RecyclerViewAdapter Class,

```
private var notes: List<Note> = ArrayList()
private var isItemMoved: Boolean = false

fun setNote(notes: List<Note>) {
    this.notes = notes
    println(isItemMoved)
    if (!isItemMoved) {
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    isItemMoved = false
}

fun isItemMoved(){
    println("set it to true")
    isItemMoved = true
}
```

Hope this helps